# Capturing a block of data after reading a URL

Tags: python, regex

I have the expected output below..am trying to read a URL,am able the read it successfully,
however when I try to capture the data under block "Combo",am running into an error,any inputs on how to resolve this?

```
# Version YYYYMMDD
version = "20121112"

# File type to be output to logs
# Should be changed to exe before building the exe.
fileType = "py"

# Import sys to read command line arguments
import sys, getopt
#import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()

import argparse
import urllib
import urllib2
import getpass
import re

def update (url):
    print url

    authhost = 'https://login.company.com'
    # Siteminder test server
    user = getpass.getuser()
    password = getpass.getpass()
    realm = None

    # handle the authentication and cookies
    cookiehand = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
    password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    password_mgr.add_password(user=user,
                              passwd=password,
                              uri=authhost,
                              realm=realm)
    auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler, cookiehand)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    #make the request
    req = urllib2.Request(url=url)
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        txt = f.read()
        f.close()
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        txt = ''
        print 'An error occured connecting to the wiki. No wiki page will be generated.'
        return '<font color=\"red\">QWiki</font>'
    # Find the start tag of the textarea with Regular Expressions
    print txt
    p = re.compile('<Combo[^>]*>')
    m = p.search(txt)
    (tagStart, tagEnd) = m.span()
    # Find the end of the textarea
    endTag = txt.index("</textarea>")

def main ():
    #For logging
    print "test"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is the update.py script created by test')
    parser.add_argument('-u','--url',action='store',dest='url',default=None,help='<Required> url link',required=True)
    results = parser.parse_args()# collect cmd line args
    url = results.url
    #print url
    update(url)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:-

```
C:\Dropbox\scripts>python announce_update.py --u "http://qwiki.company.com/component/w/index.php?title=Test1&action=raw"
test
http://qwiki.company.com/component/w/index.php?title=Test1&action=raw
Password:
==== <font color="#008000">Combo</font> ====

{| border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
|-
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test1
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test2
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test3
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test4
|-
| [http:link.com]
|}

==== <font color="#008000">COde:</font> ====
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "announce_update.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "announce_update.py", line 64, in main
    update(url)
  File "announce_update.py", line 52, in update
    (tagStart, tagEnd) = m.span()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'
```

Expected output:-

```
{| border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
|-
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test1
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test2
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test3
! bgcolor="#67B0F9" scope="col" | test4
|-
| [http:link.com]
|}
```

Comment: consider 'beautiful soup' or another html-parsing library. regexes are ill-suited for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggests that your string `m` is empty/not defined.

Furthermore it seems your regexp would not find the right piece of text anyway as it will stop at the closing bracket of `</font>`.

I found a nice reference on using `re` at http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

After reading that I think you need an expression like this

```
p = re.compile(r'>Combo<.*({.*})');
```

Note the `r` to denote `raw` string, telling Python not to interpret backslashes etc; I created a "group" with the parentheses, so you can extract "this bit of the match only". Now when you search with

```
m = p.match();
```

You should be able to extract just the bit in the first set of braces that follows `>Combo<` with

```
myText = m.group(1);
```

This may not be perfect but it should be very close - I'm attempting to show you need to find "the first opening brace after >Combo< up to the next closing brace". The parentheses are to indicate "this is the bit I want", and the indexed `group` extracts it from the `match` object.

Comment: I am actually searching for Combo..I updated the script..the source contains the string "combo",am actually printing the source too..

Comment: I saw what you printed but I still think your regex is wrong - which is why I added the tag.

Comment: you are right..I tried with your regex..still doesnt work..i will keep trying unless you have any other ideas

Comment: this is giving an error..Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "announce_update.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "announce_update.py", line 66, in main
    update(url)
  File "announce_update.py", line 51, in update
    m = p.match();
TypeError: Required argument 'pattern' (pos 1) not found

Comment: Lower case p vs upper case P?... I just noticed auto cap on ipad may have thrown that curve ball... Did you copy my code directly? I fixed it...

Answer (score 1):

`p.search(txt)` returns `None` if the pattern `p` is not found in the text `txt`. `None.span` leads to the error.

To extract text from the first `<textarea>` element in the html, you could use `BeautifulSoup` (html parser) instead of regexes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt)
print(soup.textarea.string)
```

You could try to do the same using only `HTMLParser` from stdlib:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi

try:
    from html.parser import HTMLParser
except ImportError: # Python 2
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError: # Python 2
    from urllib2 import urlopen

url = 'http://qwiki.company.com/component/w/index.php?title=Test1&action=raw'
tag = 'textarea'

class Parser(HTMLParser):
    """Extract tag's text content from html."""
    def __init__(self, html, tag):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.contents = []
        self.intag = None
        self.tag = tag
        self.feed(html)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.intag = (tag == self.tag)
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.intag = False
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.intag:
            self.contents.append(data)

# download and convert to Unicode
response = urlopen(url)
_, params = cgi.parse_header(response.headers.get('Content-Type', ''))
html = response.read().decode(params['charset'])

# parse html (extract text from the first `<tag>` element)
content = Parser(html, tag).contents[0]
print(content)
```